# Slow performance in a second POST request on SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-gateway

the community of SAPUI5 in the world is so small, so i need to see if someone can help me with this problem or an explanation of what may be happening next.

I have a UI5 application which consumes gateway services using the oDataModel, 
When I try to make a POST request, the service responds very quickly, but the second time I call the same service the times of the request increase drastically, as in 200%. ***The strangest thing of all is that the first request and the second are the same.***

In my browser, the first request has a success time of approximately 10 seconds, while the second request (which is equal to the first) has a time of 2-3 minutes.

In my browser, THE SECOND REQUEST appears with status of "Pending" for 2-3 minutes, but in gateway the request was completed correctly in like 20 seconds.

this is the way i call the oDataModel the first time and the second time.

SERVICE

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(serviceUrl);
    oModel.headers = {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Accept": "application/atom+xml,application/atomsvc+xml,application/xml,application/atom+xml",
        "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml",
        "DataServiceVersion": "2.0"
    };
    oModel.setCountSupported(false);
    oModel.setSizeLimit(this._maxSize);
    oModel.attachRequestFailed(this.showLoadError);
```

then, in my controller i do the following.

CONTROLLER

```
function initializeOrders(){
var oParameters = {
        Lgnum: localStorage.Yard,
        PlanStatus: "",
        Orders: [{}],
        Transports: [{}]
    };

    oModel.create("/IncomingSet", oParameters,
        null,
        jQuery.proxy(this._readODataOnSuccess, this),
        jQuery.proxy(this._readODataOnError, this)
    )}
```

This initializeOrders function is executed when the application is started and it is also executed when I want to refresh the application information if there were changes.

If someone can help me with this question I will be very grateful because not in the sap forums I have not found anything good

Comment: i'm not a UI5 guy, but have you tried putting a fiddler proxy between browser and server to see if requests are actually identical and whether the result is from a delay on the server side or on your client side?

Comment: The ODataModel you're using [is deprecated](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/03/stop-using-sap.ui.model.odata.odatamodel-aka-v1-odatamodel-its-deprecated-since-2014/). It sends many requests synchronously instead of async which might be one of the reasons for the poor performance. Try to replace it with [v2.ODataModel](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel). Be aware that there are some settings which are active by default such as `useBatch`.

Comment: I'm using the version 1.38.7 of SAPUI5 so my ODataModel is not deprecated yet, but i will try if the v2 work better.

Comment: Tried with a new version of ODataModel but doesnt work... maybe its a gateway problem. . .

Comment: The model has been [deprecated since a long time ago](https://blogs.sap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/ui5-1.30.6-1.png) (even in 1.38.7). Besides that, what kind of errors do you get if you migrate to v2.ODataModel?

Comment: I have no errors if i migrate to the v2 of odata model, but the pending request times are equals as the v1 model... so... its not problem of the odatamodel, its from gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the rendering of some controls, but the chrome console show like pending because of that. this must be closed, as a solution for all the people who find this problem:

-If you have a control that uses a big amount of data coming from the service always try to use it on demand, the amount of data can block the memory of the browser. In example, a dynamic combobox charged with model

the best practice is just to set the model when you need it

maybe its a bug from Chrome or i dont know, well... its solved... 2 weeks to solve this.